# Javascript - Point object towards mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d-games

I'm trying to get this player character to point towards the mouse pointer, but it doesn't move at all. I have no idea where to start, can somebody please help me?

Here is the full code:

The part which I need help with is in the updatevalues() function in the player object (javascript)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("tanks-canvas");
var game = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.height = screen.height / 1.175;
canvas.width = screen.width / 1.05;
game.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
clear();
txt(0, 0, "Loading...", "100px georgia", "rgb(0, 0, 0)");

var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;
var angle;
var mode = "menu";
var key = [];
var scale = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= 255; i += 1) {
 key[i] = false;
}

/*
 Class Definition:
*/

// Bodies:
var circle_body = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
 radius: 100,
 
 draw: function() {
  this.setvals();
  circ(this.x, this.y, this.radius, "rgb(0, 150, 255)");
 },
 setvals: function() {
  this.radius = 25 * scale;
 }
};

// Turrents:

var rect_turrent = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
 width: 0,
 height: 0,
 offset: 0,
 
 draw: function() {
  this.setvals();
  
  rect(this.x + this.offset, this.y, this.width, this.height, "rgb(150, 150, 150)");
 },
 setvals: function() {
  this.offset = 35 * scale;
  this.width = 30 * scale;
  this.height = 15 * scale;
 }
};

// Classes:

var base = {
 draw: function() {
  rect_turrent.draw();
  circle_body.draw();
 }
};

/*
 Functions & Objects
*/

function txt(x, y, content, font, color) {
 game.fillStyle = color;
 game.textAlign = "center";
 game.font = font;
 game.fillText(content, x, y);
}

function rect(x, y, width, height, color) {
 x -= width / 2;
 y -= height / 2;
 game.fillStyle = color;
 game.strokeStyle = color.black;
 game.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
 game.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
 
}

function img(x, y, img) {
 x -= img.width / 2;
 y -= img.height / 2;
 game.drawImage(img, x, y);
}

function circ(x, y, radius, color) {
 game.fillStyle = color;
 game.strokeStyle = color.black;
 game.beginPath();
 game.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
 game.fill();
 game.stroke();
}

function clear() {
 rect(0, 0, canvas.width + 10, canvas.height + 10, "rgb(200, 200, 200)");
}

/*
 IMPORTANT: Player Character:
*/

var player = {
 // Variables
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
 type: "base",
 angle: 0,
 autorotate: false,
 
 // Functions
 
 update: function() {
  this.updatevalues();
  game.save();
  game.rotate(this.angle);
  this.draw();
  game.restore();
  txt(0, -100, "Mouse x: " + mousex + " | Mouse y: " + mousey + " | Angle: " + this.angle, "20px georgia", "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
 },
 draw: function() {
  if (this.type == "base") {
   base.draw();
  }
 },
 updatevalues: function() {
  this.offsetY = mousex - this.x;
  this.offsetX = mousey - this.y;
  this.angle = Math.atan(mousex / mousey);
 }
};

function menu() {
 player.update();
}

function update() {
 if (mode == "menu") {
  menu();
 }
 clear();
 player.update();
}

/*
 Intervals:
*/

game.interval = setInterval(update, 50);

/*
 Event Listeners
*/

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
 for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
  if (event.keyCode == i) {
   key[i] = true;
  }
 }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
 for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
  key[i] = false;
 }
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
 mousex = event.offsetX - (canvas.width / 2);
 mousey = (canvas.height / 2) - event.offsetY;
});
```

```css
/* Everything */

* {
 transition: 1s;
}

body {
 background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

/* Flexbox: */

.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 5vw;
}

#header {
 flex-direction: row;
 background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
}

#main {
 background-color: rgb(200, 150, 50);
}

#navbar {
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%
}

/* Images */

img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.imgcontainer {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%
}

.imgoverlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.75);
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
}

.imgtext {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75);
}

.imgcontainer:hover .imgoverlay {
 height: 100%;
}

.image {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

/* Navigation Menu */

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 5vw;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 1vw 1vw 1vw 4vw;
    text-decoration: none;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    display: block;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1vw;
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Styles: */

h1 {
 font: 10vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 200);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

h2 {
 font: 9vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 150);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

h3 {
 font: 8vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 150);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

h4 {
 font: 7vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 150);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

h5 {
 font: 6vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 150);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

h6 {
 font: 5vw courier;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 150);
 text-align: center;
 padding: none;
}

p {
 font: 2vw georgia;
 color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
 text-align: justify;
}

/* Other */

.link {
 color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.link:hover {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

code {
 font-family: courier;
}

canvas {
 padding: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 display: block;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Game Goods</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  
  <!-- Game -->
  <canvas id="tanks-canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="tanks-script.js"></script>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

(If you run it, hit "full page", or it won't work.)

Edit 10-30-18: I've changed the code according to Helder's answer. At least the mousex works now...

Edit 10-31-18: I changed mousex and mousey to also be at coordinates 0, 0 when the mouse is at the middle. The canvas works like a coordinate plane now. I also added debugging text (you can see it if you run the snippet).

Comment: `console.log(mousex, mousey, this.angle)` You will see the mouse changes, but your angle calculation never does....

Comment: Your this.x and this.y are 0,0.... but it is in the middle.... so that looks to be wrong.

Comment: I'm translating it to be in the middle, because the canvas rotates around the coordinates 0, 0.

Comment: Yes, you need to adjust it to be coordinates in the middle.... You are saying it is in the upper left

Comment: When I translate it, 0, 0 _becomes_ the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the formula with help from my math teacher & a different question.

The formula is

```
Math.atan2(-y, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations for the angle are incorrect, take a look at this sample...

This is by no means the exact solution but should get you moving on the right direction, I'm only using mousex in my calculation.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("tanks-canvas");
var game = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.height = canvas.width = 170;
game.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
clear();

var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;
var angle;
var mode = "menu";
var key = [];
var scale = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= 255; i += 1) {
  key[i] = false;
}

var player = {
  x: 0,  y: 0,
  type: "base",
  angle: 0,
  autorotate: false,

  update: function() {
    this.updatevalues();
    game.save()
    game.rotate(this.angle);
    this.draw();
    game.restore();
  },
  updatevalues: function() {
    this.offsetY = mousex - this.x;
    this.offsetX = mousey - this.y;
    this.angle = 360 * Math.sin(mousex/30000);    
  },
  draw: function() {
    if (this.type == "base") {
      base.draw();
    }
  }  
};

/*
 Class Definition:
*/

// Bodies:
var circle_body = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  radius: 100,

  draw: function() {
    this.setvals();
    circ(this.x, this.y, this.radius, "rgb(0, 150, 255)");
  },
  setvals: function() {
    this.radius = 25 * scale;
  }
};

// Turrents:

var rect_turrent = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  offset: 0,

  draw: function() {
    this.setvals();

    rect(this.x + this.offset, this.y, this.width, this.height, "rgb(150, 150, 150)");
  },
  setvals: function() {
    this.offset = 35 * scale;
    this.width = 30 * scale;
    this.height = 15 * scale;
  }
};

// Classes:

var base = {
  draw: function() {
    rect_turrent.draw();
    circle_body.draw();
  }
};

/*
 Functions & Objects
*/


function rect(x, y, width, height, color) {
  x -= width / 2;
  y -= height / 2;
  game.fillStyle = color;
  game.strokeStyle = color.black;
  game.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  game.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);

}

function circ(x, y, radius, color) {
  game.fillStyle = color;
  game.strokeStyle = color.black;
  game.beginPath();
  game.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  game.fill();
  game.stroke();
}

function clear() {
  rect(0, 0, canvas.width + 10, canvas.height + 10, "rgb(200, 200, 200)");
}


function update() {
  clear();
  player.update();
}


game.interval = setInterval(update, 50);


document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mousex = event.offsetX;
  mousey = event.offsetY;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="tanks-canvas"></canvas>
```